# Match only entire words with LIKE?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-like

So 'awesome document' LIKE '%doc%' is true, because doc is a sub-string. But, I want it to be false while 'awesome doc' or 'doc awesome' or 'awesome doc awesome' should be true. How can I do with with a like?

I'm using sqlite, so I hope I don't have to use something that isn't available.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444300/search-for-whole-word-match-with-sql-server-like-pattern

Comment: What about other characters like punctuation or symbols?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

How about split it into four parts -

```
[MyColumn] Like '% doc %' 
OR [MyColumn] Like '% doc' 
OR [MyColumn] Like 'doc %' 
OR [MyColumn] = 'doc'
```

Edit: An alternate approach (only for ascii chars) could be:

```
'#'+[MyColumn]+'#' like '%[^a-z0-9]doc[^a-z0-9]%'
```

(You may want to take care of any special char as well)

It doesn't look like, but you may want to explore [Full Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142547.aspx) and [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), in case that's more suitable for your situation.

See:
- [MSDN: [ ] (Wildcard - Character(s) to Match) (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179884%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 Because this is the only approach I can think of, but it makes me shiver.

Comment: Don't forget the case where the string is just 'doc'.

Comment: (See other answers about matching case of "doc").

Comment: If I have sentence with "doc" at begin, and a comma follow (Ex: "doc, thank you!"), I think it cannot search

Comment: I think this is incorrect in the scenario of "xxxxdoc xxxxx ". Pattern 'doc %' will match this.

Answer (score 11):

you can just use below condition:

```
(' '+YOUR_FIELD_NAME+' ') like '% doc %'
```

it works faster than other solutions.

Comment: what if word is "doc?"

Comment: @Zeeshanef nothing, it just works ' ' + 'doc' + ' ' fits '% doc %'

Answer (score 8):

```
WHERE (@string LIKE 'doc %' OR @string LIKE '% doc' OR @string LIKE '% doc %' OR @string = 'doc')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use some ORs, LIKE '% doc %' OR LIKE 'doc %' OR LIKE '% doc' OR LIKE 'doc'

Comment: +1 For including the "doc" case, but might be better written as `=` there.

Answer (score 1):

LIKE is quite limited. I would suggest REGEXP, for example:

```
 columnName REGEXP 'doc[;.?!,") ]'
```

for example: awesome document wouldn't match, but 
awesome **doc**, 
**doc** awesome, 
awesome **doc** awesome will match.

It will also match an existing word in text followed by punctuation characters.
You can try any example here: https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me (SQL Server 2008 R2).

But I managed to get it to work using somewhat of the answers shown below..

```
SELECT * FROM myTable AS v
WHERE v.Note LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]CONTainers[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

**Note:** v.Note is a TEXT data type

This worked for me with the following samples..

- containers
- CONTAINERS
- conTaInERS

But not when the word 'containers' was surrounded by other letters or numerics..

- 001containers001
- AAcontainersAA

Which is what the OP asked for in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEX with "word boundary" [MySql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

So, in your example : 'awesome document' REGEXP '\bdoc\b'

Answer (score 0):

In more modern SQL Servers you can use the STRING_SPLIT function to do this easily.

The following link splits on spaces.

```
SELECT * FROM DataTable T WHERE 'doc' IN (SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(T.TextField, ' '))
```

If you wanted to include commas, periods, question marks, semicolons and exclamation points ie ",.?;!" you can add a translate.

```
SELECT * FROM DataTable T WHERE 'doc' IN (SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(TRANSLATE(T.TextField, ',.?;!', '     '), ' '))
```

Answer (score -6):

What about `NOT LIKE '%doc%'`?

Comment: The task is to find only the word "DOC" -- not a partial word as in "DOCument"

Comment: I think the question is to use LIKE to match the whole word, but not as a part of another word.