# Sql like with each word starting charcter

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite

My table:

```
create table product (
  nama_product varchar(20)
);

insert into product values
('ayam bakar'),
('daging ayam'),
('bayam hijau'),
('daun bayam');
```

Current Query:

```
select nama_product
  from product
 where nama_product regexp '(^| )ayam( |$)';
```

I am got the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37234783/7273263.

I want to search char or word from text value. Current query i am getting the accurate result but problem is thar i have to give entire word.

But i want to get the result if 'aya' instead of 'ayam'

```
select nama_product
      from product
     where nama_product regexp '(^| )aya( |$)';
```

I have tried with `'%ayam%'` but it searched result if middle of the word..

i need to get the same result with input `'aya'` Please let me know,

i need specific answer in mysql & sql ;sql lite or any one

Edit: Required Result:

```
nama_product
ayam bakar
daging ayam
```

Comment: If you only want to match the beginning of the word, get rid of `( |$)` after the word.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar it will same for sql lite also rite

Comment: Yes. This is basic regular expression, should work with any engine.

Comment: Then you should read a tutorial. Don't just copy code without understanding how it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 Like Impression:**

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE nama_product like'aya_%' or nama_product like'% aya_';
```

**Solution 2 Regular Impression:**

```
SELECT nama_product
      FROM product
     WHERE nama_product regexp '(^| )aya';
```