# SQL Match individual word?

Tags: php, sql

I am using **like** statement: **%word%** but the problem is it also matches words that are inside other words.

How can I match words that are separate from the rest in the string like this. I wanna match word1 in these strings:

**word1** word2 word3

word2 **word1** word3

word2 word3 **word1**

And don't match this: **word2word1**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Match only entire words with LIKE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283767/match-only-entire-words-with-like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is: match the space too.

```
col LIKE '% doc %' OR col LIKE '% doc' OR col LIKE 'doc %' OR col = 'doc'
```

Comment: Thanks but I am afraid it will also match occurrences of that word in other! Is there a maybe regular extension for it. If not 100% match skip?

Comment: @letsforum sorry but can't follow you. Can you give an example explaining what you mean?

Comment: Sorry buddy. I mean if I use this: col LIKE '% doc %' OR col LIKE '% doc' OR col LIKE 'doc %' OR col = 'doc' will it match 100% the entire word and skip matching occurrences of that word in others?  LIKE '% doc' will return words that start with my word to match etc.

Comment: @letsforum No I don't think so. `% doc` only matchs `abcd[space]doc`, not `abcddoc` neither `abc docefg`

Comment: @letsforum for further information, see mysql document.

Comment: Sorry I am only scratching the surface on PHP and SQL. Thanks gonna try it!

Comment: You're welcome :) If it works, then you can select me as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this in generic SQL is like this:

```
where ' ' || col || ' ' like '% word1 %'
```

Note that the operator for string concatenation may vary among databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSTR` function to get the string required exactly

```
WHERE column_name = INSTR(column_name,'word')
```

INSTR - Instring function matches the string provided in the function. Rather than using like operator, this function provides you required result. Also like operator searches all the possible combinations and takes more time compared to INSTR function. To increase performance INSTR function can be used.

Comment: Hope you got it