# Laravel Eloquent Problem - can't search for single word

Tags: laravel

Hi I am trying to write a search function that finds all the service name with the keyword

```
$serviceids = Service::where('service_name', 'like', '%' . $key . '%')->pluck('service_recordid');
```

Here is what I have right now but when I search for 'rent' this result also returns 'parent' since rent is included. What can I do to make the condition to be a unique word of its own?

Comment: Check this answer out, I think you can do what you want with regex - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5743583/1594754

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current search uses `%` before and after the searchterm. By doing so you actually add the behaviour you don't want - your search for anything that CONTAINS your term.

```
$serviceids = Service::where('service_name', $key)->pluck('service_recordid');
```

A simple where without `like` and `%` will return any serviceId with the exact key as name

Edit: If you want to ensure a full match to a word you can do it with multiple where clauses ([Match only entire words with LIKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283767/match-only-entire-words-with-like))

```
$serviceids = Service::where('service_name', 'like', '% ' . $key . ' %')
                       ->orWhere('service_name', 'like', '% ' . $key)
                       ->orWhere('service_name', 'like', $key . ' %')
                       ->orWhere('service_name', $key)
                       ->pluck('service_recordid');
```

the spaces are key to ensure it has a direct fit

Comment: Is there anything that I can use to find 'this rent payment' by the keyword rent but excluding things like 'parent'? I think the hint you are given is searching for the exact matching key.

Comment: you could add a space? `'% rent%'`

Comment: I've updatet my answer accordingly