# SQL search last name in full name

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having an issue in searching last name in full name. It is working with **%%** but I don't what to use it because all has 'A' are showing. Is there any alternative way on search last name? For example I have a full name **John Doe** and I only searched **Doe**, how to get the result even if I searched the last name?

**SELECT * FROM Customers where CustomerName LIKE '%Doe%' - this is working**

Comment: So if the customer name is `Doe John`, you don't want to get his result?

Comment: @Arulkumar i still want to get the result either way even if John Doe or Doe John

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Match only entire words with LIKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283767/match-only-entire-words-with-like)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table_name where Column_Name Like "%last_name"
```

- that will select only full names ends by **last_name**

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am shown you. Please, try this both of one.

```
SELECT FullName FROM dbo.TableA where FullName LIKE '%Choksi%'

SELECT  SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, LEN(FullName)) AS [Last Name]
  from dbo.TableA
 where FullName like '%Choksi%'
```