# Search for “exact word match” in a Datatable using a regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, datatable

According to this link [Search for “whole word match” with SQL Server LIKE pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444300/search-for-whole-word-match-with-sql-server-like-pattern)

I want to follow the same query string but in a datatable I've written the following statement

Assume datatable contains the following records

```
datatable[0]["src"]="tst";
datatable[1]["src"]="tst,";
datatable[2]["src"]="tst:";
datatable[3]["src"]="disney";

int p=datatable.AsEnumerable().Select(a => Regex.IsMatch(a["src"].ToString(), "[^a-z]windows[^a-z]")).Count();
```

but the result was p = 4  while this word 'windows' exists only 3 times

And in case of using 'where' instead of 'select' as following

```
int p=datatable.AsEnumerable().Where(a => Regex.IsMatch(a["src"].ToString(), "[^a-z]windows[^a-z]")).Count();
```

p is always 0

What's wrong in my statement ..Any advice?!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"the result was p = datatable rows count while this word 'windows' doesn't exist in all rows"*  Are you saying that it's returning a count of all rows, and not a count of only the rows containing the word "windows"?

Comment: this statement returns all datatable rows count while the key word 'windows' exist in some of these rows not all of them

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not clear what you mean.  Tell us what you expect  p to contain, and what it actually contains.

Comment: Your second example will work, if you can fix your regex so that you get matches.  Check your regex here: http://regexpal.com/.  See also [How to match whole words with a regular expression](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/217-how-to-match-whole-words-with-a-regular-expression/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example (`Select`) runs the operation on all rows in the data table.  The result would be a list of Boolean values indicating whether the row value matched the expression.

In both cases, your pattern is *requiring* a non-alpha in front of and after the word "windows", which results in it not matching.  In the first case, you would get a list containing 4 "false" values, and in the second you get nothing.

I believe the simplest regex to get what you want is probably something like:

```
"\bwindows\b"
```

(Using Robert Harvey's suggested regex.  This pattern asserts that there is a "word break" - including nothing - before and after the word.)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'll go with that, though the LIKE matching wouldn't assert a whole-word match either.

Comment: This is what happens when people lift code without understanding how it works.

Answer (score 0):

`Select` and `Where` aren't interchangeable - your select will return a `true` or `false` value for each record, which is why your count is 4 (because you have 4 records and thus 4 return values.

Your where clause returning 0 tells me your RegEx is not matching values 0-2.  I would verify that the RegEx works as expected.

Comment: Your regex also matches `xwindows`.

Comment: Given that there was very little detail regarding EXACTLY what the OP was expecting to match I made a guess...

Comment: yes as @RobertHarvey said your regex match i.e. xwindows i want to match the same keyword only in addition to take into consideration punctuation like semicolon, comma ,.. etc. like (windows;)

Comment: OK, but "whole word match" is in the title of his question. ;)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Good point.  I took out my suggestion and will leave it at "get the RegEx to work first"