# Searching for whole words using '%[^a-zA-Z]searchword[^a-zA-Z]%'

Tags: regex, sql-server-2005

Does anyone know how to search for whole words using '%[^a-zA-Z]Word[^a-zA-Z]%' and find the words if there is no text after it?

If I use the code below, I don't get the 'Success' message.
if PATINDEX(('%[^A-Za-z]' + 'word' + '[^A-Za-z]%'),'Find the word') > 0 select 'Success'

But if use this code below, I do get the 'Success' message.
if PATINDEX(('%[^A-Za-z]' + 'word' + '[^A-Za-z]%'),'Find the word go') > 0 select 'Success'

It will only match the words that have text before or after it.

Answer (score 2):

```
\bdog\b
```

Should do it.  Provided there is a word boundary at both edges...

Comment: Only if they enable CLR and use proper regular expressions rather than the pattern syntax in the question. The regex tag was not added by the OP.

Comment: The Patindex is required for other parts of code in the proc previously. I just took out a small chunk to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

... just to connect the dots, based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5444529:

When the column has a _CI (case insensitive) collation:

```
patindex('%[^a-z]word[^a-z]%', '.' + Column + '.') > 0
```

When the column has a _CS (case sensitive) collation (or might):

```
patindex('%[^a-zA-Z][wW][oO][rR][dD][^a-zA-Z]%', '.' + Column + '.') > 0
```