# SQL identify whether a word in nvarchar variable is listed in lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a procedure to automatically overwrite profane words entered by a user on a form and replace the text with asterisks if the word in question is in a lookup database.

For the sake of this example, let's assume Flubber is a rude word in our Profanity table and we need to flag it when it's entered as a word on its own. 'Flubber' needs to be flagged as inappropriate, 'Flubbermost' is fine.

User enters: I really like watching Flubber.

What I ultimately want to do is update the data in the field with: I really like watching *******. Or some variation of that, perhaps F****r.

I've tried using `CONTAINS` (and I'm just trying to identify whether we have a profane word at this stage)

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @String = N'I really like watching Flubber'
SELECT MyWord FROM MyLookup WHERE CONTAINS(MyWord,@String)
```

but I get the following message

> Msg 7630, Level 15, State 3, Line 4
>   Syntax error near 'really' in the full-text search condition 'I really like watching Flubber'.

Any help would be gratefully received.

EDIT:

Following help from AHiggins I've added a Full Text Index and the following code works well:

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(4000) 
DECLARE @MatchedWord NVARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @ReturnString NVARCHAR(4000) 
SET varString = 'i really like watching Flubber' 
SELECT varMatchedWord = MyWord FROM MyLookup WHERE FREETEXT (DESCR,@String) 
PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(4000),@MatchedWord)
```

And this returns data when the whole word is found - perfect.

Onto the second part of my question: what's the best way of substituting the word 'Flubber' with '*******' please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your new requirements, I'm actually going to point you towards [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444300/search-for-whole-word-match-with-sql-server-like-pattern) that suggests (strongly) you use the Full Text Search functionality in SQL Server.  If that is unavailable, though, you can take the performance hit of doing this yourself and use the following code:

```
SELECT MyWord, @String AS SearchPhrase 
FROM MyLookup 
WHERE '.' + @String + '.' LIKE '%[^a-z]'+MyWord+'[^a-z]%'
```

Full example with sample data:

```
DECLARE @MyLookup TABLE (MyWord VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @MyLookup (MyWord) VALUES ('Flubber')

DECLARE @String nVARCHAR(4000)


SET @String = N'I really like watching Flubbers'
SELECT MyWord, @String AS SearchPhrase FROM @MyLookup WHERE '.' + @String + '.' LIKE '%[^a-z]'+MyWord+'[^a-z]%'

SET @String = N'I really like watching Flubber.'
SELECT MyWord, @String AS SearchPhrase FROM @MyLookup WHERE '.' + @String + '.' LIKE '%[^a-z]'+MyWord+'[^a-z]%'

SET @String = N'I really like watching Flubber, is that weird?'
SELECT MyWord, @String AS SearchPhrase FROM @MyLookup WHERE '.' + @String + '.' LIKE '%[^a-z]'+MyWord+'[^a-z]%'

SET @String = N'I really like watching the Flubber movie'
SELECT MyWord, @String AS SearchPhrase FROM @MyLookup WHERE '.' + @String + '.' LIKE '%[^a-z]'+MyWord+'[^a-z]%'

SET @String = N'I really like watching Flubber!'
SELECT MyWord, @String AS SearchPhrase FROM @MyLookup WHERE '.' + @String + '.' LIKE '%[^a-z]'+MyWord+'[^a-z]%'

SET @String = N'I really like watchingFlubber'
SELECT MyWord, @String AS SearchPhrase FROM @MyLookup WHERE '.' + @String + '.' LIKE '%[^a-z]'+MyWord+'[^a-z]%'
```

EDIT: talk about a moving target ... I've taken the code from your comment (using full text search) and printed off a return string to replace the word with asterisks.

Note that if the word shows multiple times in the same search string, this will replace all instances. I don't have access to an instance with full text search enabled, so you'll have to confirm that this is working as expected.

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(4000) 
DECLARE @MatchedWord NVARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @ReturnString NVARCHAR(4000) 
SET @String = 'i really like watching Flubber' 

SELECT 
    @MatchedWord = MyWord,
    @ReturnString = REPLACE(@String, MyWord, REPLICATE('*', LEN(MyWord)))
FROM MyLookup 
WHERE FREETEXT (DESCR,@String) 

PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(4000), @MatchedWord)
PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(4000), @ReturnString)
```

Comment: Nice one AHiggins, thanks. The next thing I need to check for, that I forgot to add to the OP - I will update. Is if the word is found on its own. For example, String = N'Flubbermost' is okay, String = N'Flubber' is not okay and needs to be flagged.

Comment: So, your conditions have expanded: you now need to know if it is a standalone word (space, punctuation, or end of string afterwards). Is that correct?

Comment: Edited with new answer, then.  Let me know if this works for you ... it'll be a performance hit, and you might be better off investigating the Full Text Search functionality to see if you can get it working.

Comment: Thanks. Full Text Index added and the following code works well:

    DECLARE varString NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE varMatchedWord NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE varReturnString NVARCHAR(4000)
    SET varString = 'i really like watching Flubber'

    SELECT varMatchedWord = MyWord FROM MyLookup WHERE FREETEXT (DESCR,varString)
    PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(4000),varMatchedWord)

Returns data when the whole word is found - perfect.

Onto the second part of my question: what's the best way of substituting the word 'Flubber' with '*******' please?

@ replaced with var in declaration to allow posting.

Comment: Nope ... you can [format comments to some degree](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/text-formatting-now-allowed-in-comments-list-of-proven-and-disproven-abilities), but things like this are probably better as edits to your original question.  Check the new code sample.

Comment: Thanks AHiggins. The new code sample works perfectly. Should I be concerned about the message 'Informational: The full-text search condition contained noise word(s).' returned by Enterprise Manager?

Comment: I don't think so ... if you're concerned about it, you can search for the message text and see what's up, and if you have questions then you can always post a new one.