# select query to retrieve exact word matching from a list of word in mssql

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-like

[403 image link by OP]

Above image is of my database table in Mssql server. I want to select the data which only contains `arrTransactionColumns` from `report_keys` column.

My query is

```
select * from table where report_keys like '%arrTransactionColumns%'
```

but it gives the result which has `arrTransactionColumnsHRI` too.

Comment: USE equal to operator. Why you are using like operator?

Comment: equal to operator will retrieve only those rows where report_key contains arrTransactionColumns..but i want all those row which has arrTransaction in it

Comment: explain what you want exactly

Comment: i want query like this...Select * from table where if arrTransactionColumns is present if any row of report_keys then show the resluting rows

Comment: is this is what you want : You want all rows having  arrTransaction. It must include arrTransactionColumns but avoid arrTransactionColumnsHRI. If the value is 'arrTransactionColu' is it is included or avoided.

Comment: yes..thats exactly what i want..it should be avoided

Comment: What happen if the value is  'arrTran' and  What happen if the value is 'arrTransaction345565'

Comment: then it should be avoided also

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search for “whole word match” with SQL Server LIKE pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444300/search-for-whole-word-match-with-sql-server-like-pattern)

Comment: Put table structure. Sqlfiddler with Sample data. and expected answer with examble and all possibilities. Else remove the question.

Comment: try this link from stack overflow itself.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444300/search-for-whole-word-match-with-sql-server-like-pattern)

Comment: The link to the image of the schema is dead. Don't provide information as image which can be text.

Answer (score 0):

try  use `CHARINDEX`

```
 select * 
    from TABLE 
    WHERE CHARINDEX('arrTransactionColumns',report_keys )>0
```

Comment: Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'ReportColumnTbl' because it is not full-text indexed.

Comment: what if the report_key column has arrTransactionColumnsHRI only.i want to avoid the rows in which the report_key column contains arrTransactionColumnsHRI only

Comment: FOR arrTransactionColumnsHRI YOU WILL GET 0 ROWS

Comment: you should try it.it works both for contain and equal