# SQLite query with [^] not working

Tags: android, regex, sqlite

I checked the many posts on SO and they seem to match what I'm doing, but I can't get it to work, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.
Like many others, I'm trying to match only words and not partial matches, I tried all the [^a-zA-Z] and nothing matches, so I tried to narrow it down to a simpler testcase, it seems like the [ ] don't work at all for me. I'm using this code:

```html
String flashcardSearchQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + COLUMN_ENGLISH_WORD +
        " LIKE " + "'%" + search_str + "[^,]%'";

ArrayList<Flashcard> flashList = new ArrayList<>();

SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(flashcardSearchQuery, null);
```

so when I search for 'all', it should match these:

```
all  
mall  
all or nothing
```

but not these:

```
all, whole  
recall, wow
```

But I get nothing. Similar when I try w/o the '^' and just "[,]%" nothing matches, what am I missing ?

I see this output in the debugger, so the concatenation seems to work, right ?

SELECT * FROM words where english_word LIKE '%little[^,]%'

**[UPDATE]** Great, both suggestions (`REGEXP`/`GLOB`) work:

```html
String flashcardSearchQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + COLUMN_ENGLISH_WORD +
        " GLOB " + "'*[^a-zA-Z]" + search_str + "[^a-zA-Z]*'";

String flashcardSearchQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + COLUMN_ENGLISH_WORD +
        " REGEXP " + "'.*[^a-zA-Z]" + search_str + "[^a-zA-Z].*'";
```

Now I only have to figure out how to include cases where the search term is the final word e.g.

all
this is all

Funny, many references do seem to suggest that `LIKE` should work with [] ...

**[2ND UPDATE]** I just settled for a 2 liner, though not versed enough in regexp to understand why it covers even the 'start' permutations:

```html
String flashcardSearchQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " where " +
        COLUMN_ENGLISH_WORD + " REGEXP '.*[^a-zA-Z]" + search_str + "[^a-zA-Z].*' OR " +
        COLUMN_ENGLISH_WORD + " REGEXP '.*[^a-zA-Z]" + search_str + "'";
```

Comment: AFAIK, `LIKE` does not support the syntax you are trying. See http://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html.

Comment: but they had an accepted answer here, using LIKE, no ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444300/search-for-whole-word-match-with-sql-server-like-pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**LIKE** is not strong enough to use regex.

Try using **REGEXP**

`Select * from table_name where some_string REGEXP '.*all[^,\.]*'`

Comment: Just add a space before the search term to make it a final word

Comment: sorry, not sure where, in front of 'all' ? How would that work ? I could probably solve it with an ``OR`` but I'm hoping for a single expression to cover all my bases.

Answer (score 2):

May be this should work, i.e adding two where clauses with logical and to satisfy both, one for search string and other for no comma

```
String flashcardSearchQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + COLUMN_ENGLISH_WORD + " LIKE " + "'%" + search_str + "%' AND "  + COLUMN_ENGLISH_WORD + " NOT LIKE '%,%'";
```

Comment: that was my fallback, but I want to cover a lot of exception, that would make this one too tedious

Comment: In that case I'd suggest is to put all your exceptions in a table. Join to this table to exclude rows.

Answer (score 1):

The LIKE operator does not support character ranges.

Use [GLOB](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) instead:

```
... WHERE EnglishWord GLOB '*little[^,]*'
```